# How can I get the image width to fill the card and the height to be flexible?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flexbox

I'm trying to set the dimensions of the image so that the width will always take up the full width of the card (minus the horizontal margin) and with a flexible height, so that it can scale as it needs to.

How can I do this? It seems that the style needs a height, it won't accept null.

I have tried a LOT of combinations using various resizeModes, heights, widths etc.

Here is the component:

[image]

And here is my current code:

```
 renderImage(image) {
    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

    if (image) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
          <Image
            style={{ width, resizeMode: 'contain', height: 300 }}
            source={{ uri: image }}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `aspectRatio` property solves this problem nicely.

```
<Image
  style={{ width: '100%', aspectRatio: 1 }}
  source={{uri: 'https://online.picture/dynamic_size'}}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem for images from web (where no exact width & height was known) and created [react-native-web-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-web-image). Currently not for local images, only for remote. Try it, I will be glad if it will help.

Comment: I can't do that I'm afraid. I'm using exponent which doesn't support native modules.

Comment: In that case I can suggest use two-step logic: fist `Image.getSize` (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#getsize) to retrieve original dimensions, then you can calculate all needed dimensions to scale properly.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width to be the screen width, and set height to be `undefined`.

Comment: The style needs a height, it won't accept null or omission. If I do so, the image won't render at all.

Comment: What's the style of imageContainer?

Comment: Just this : `marginHorizontal: 10,
    marginBottom: 5,`